# Kernel dead in jupyter notebook, matplotlib seems not to work

Tags: 16.04, kernel, anaconda, matplotlib, jupyter

I recently updated my anaconda package with $conda update conda and then $conda update anaconda
After that update my matplotlib is not working anymore and every time I try to run Jupyter notebook and import matplotlib, it says 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'

And it leaves with a ton of message starting like this:

```
Bad key "patch.force_edgecolor" on line 33 in
/home/trina/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/_classic_test.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and python 2.7 . Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mess up the matplotlib that you already have installed in Anaconda, you can install second instance of matplotlib inside a Python virtual environment (*virtualenv*) alongside  the matplotlib that is installed in Anaconda. Installing Jupyter, matplotlib and whatever else you need with pip is easy and straightforward in virtualenv.

*virtualenv* allows you to create a sandboxed and isolated environment where Python packages can be installed without interfering with other packages on the same machine.

1. Install Python virtual environment creator (*virtualenv*):

   ```
   sudo apt install python-virtualenv virtualenv # still works in 22.04
   ```
2. Make a new directory (I'll call it PythonVirtualEnv in this example) for the Python virtual environment and setup the Python virtual environment with Python and pip in it.

   ```
   cd ~  
   mkdir PythonVirtualEnv
   virtualenv PythonVirtualEnv
   ```
3. Install some packages.

   ```
   cd ~/PythonVirtualEnv  
   source bin/activate
   python -m pip install jupyter matplotlib
   ```
4. Deactivate the Python virtual environment before leaving it.

   ```
   deactivate
   ```

#### Creating an environment with a custom Python interpreter

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv 
cd ~  
mkdir Python3VirtualEnv
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 Python3VirtualEnv # /usr/bin/python3 is the default location of the python3 executable
cd ~/Python3VirtualEnv  
source bin/activate
python3 -m pip install jupyter matplotlib
```